# Как сделать обратный отсчет введенных символов в textarea?

Tags: jquery, html5, javascript

Есть форма для отправки комментария на сайт:

```
<form action="comments.php" action="post" id="comments">
        <fildset>
          <legend>Отправить комментарий</legend>
          <label for="name"><input id="name" type="text" name="name"></label>
          <label for="email"><input id="email" type="email" name="email"></label>
          <label for="url"><input id="url" type="url" name="url"></label>
          <label for="message"><textarea name="" id="message" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea></label>
          <p>
            <output></output>
          </p>
          <button class="btn btn-primary">Отправить</button>
        </fildset>
      </form>
```

Задача, когда посетитель наводит фокус на textarea в output появляется число 500 и с каждым введенным символом уменьшается на единицу, в принципе задача не сильно сложная. Как лучше реализовать?

Comment: fi**e**ldset

Answer (score 2):

лучше через

http://jsfiddle.net/dHF74/

Но можно и на чистом JS извратнуться

Comment: Я мало понимаю в js/jquery но по моему вы и на jquery извратнулись.

Comment: Ну да, лучше вообще готовый JqueryUI использовать.

Comment: Простите, я имел ввиду сам ваш код, по моему он стремный.

Comment: @knes, единственная рекомендация:  

    $("#message").on('input', function(){

Так будет работать со вставкой из буфера обмена.

Comment: О, за on.input спасибо. Только ча совместимость уточню.

Comment: @knes https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers.oninput#Browser_compatibility

Comment: Еще одно спасибо за input )

Answer (score 1):

```
var updateLimit = limitMsg(500, $('#limit'));

$('#textarea').on('focus input', function (e) {
    var length = $(e.target).val().length;
    updateLimit(length);
});

function limitMsg(limitValue, msgElem) {
    return function (value) {
        msgElem.text(limitValue - value);
    }
}
```

Не уверен, но скорее всего это решение не качественно работает с нажатием клавиши enter.